# How can I log information about a GraphQL request in Graphene Django?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

Currently, Django logs: `[16/Dec/2019 13:29:16] "POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 200 1735` for any incoming graphql request. I'd like to be able to log more information about the incoming request (which queries, mutations, etc it is running).

Is there a standardized way to do this, or should I just write my own middleware?